# using multiple forms as different actions in one layout leading to hash validation error

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

i have two forms in one page one for login and one for forgot password,

```
<?php echo $this->layout()->user_login = $this->action('login','user',null); ?>
<?php echo $this->layout()->user_forgot = $this->action('forgot','user',null); ?>
```

and the forms are in actions and each form has its own view,
i have a hash validator in forgot action, but when i submit the forgot form i get the error that "The two given tokens do not match", i think during the layout process , the form will be instantiated and the hash id would change :( i have no idea how to fix it ...

it is the forgot form

```
<?php
class listab_Form_Forgot extends Zend_Form
{
public function init()
{
    $this->addPrefixPath("listab_Model",'listab/Model/','decorator');
    // initialize form
    $this->setAction('/user/forgot')
         ->setMethod('post');
    // create text input for name 
    $user = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
    $user->setLabel('username or email')
         ->setOptions(array('size' => '30'))
         ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
         ->addFilter('StringTrim')
         ->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Label'))         
         ->setRequired(true);

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('subfg');
    $submit->setLabel('help me find my password')
           ->setOrder(100)
           ->setOptions(array('class' => 'submit'))
            ->setAttrib('class', 'gbox ozvbut') 
           ->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper');


    $hash = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('hashs');
    $hash->setSalt('wannaknowthisha?')  ;

    $this->addElement($user)
            ->addElement($hash)
            ->addElement($submit) ;               
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default **ttl = 1** (*time to live*) you might try and add a hop or 2 to it. It looks like you  might be instantiating the form in one action and then processing in another. This may be causing the hash to time out (maybe).

```
$hash = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('hashs');
    $hash->setSalt('wannaknowthisha?');
    $hash->setTimeout(2);//Set timeout for CSRF session token
```

Hope this helps...